# How to parse javascript object in java sent in html request?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

can you please give me an advice how to parse javascript object in java ?

I have an html form :

```
<form id="calcPrintForm" action="print.htm" method="post">
    <input name="_calcPrintInput" type="hidden">
</form>
```

and javascript called after form submit :

```
var line = new Object();
line.text = 'Object temperature';
line.value = 555
line.unit = "°C"
$("input[name='_calcPrintInput']").val(line);
```

When I get this parameter from request in my Spring controller with `request.getParameter("_calcPrintInput")`, it is String with [object Object] annotation and data inside is unreachable for me. Can you help me how to get values from this type od object ?

Thanks, Ondrej

Comment: You can't set a HTML form field's value to an object.

Comment: Yes, basically you are right. The solution is to transform it to string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the object to a string, since it is a object you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) - also include a library like [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for browsers which does not support native JSON

```
$("input[name='_calcPrintInput']").val(JSON.stringify(line));
```

This will assign the value `{"text":"Object temperature","value":555,"unit":"°C"}` to the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

to parse javascript object in java ($("input[name='_calcPrintInput']").val(line);),you must convert to a string, use JSON.stringify()

```
    $("input[name='_calcPrintInput']").val(JSON.stringify(line));
```

This will assign the value {"text":"Object temperature","value":555,"unit":"°C"} to the hidden element.